# How to display 2D Lidar data in rviz with sr_lidar1_scan and nodder_angle

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this are all my rostopic list

```
mit@mit-HP-Pro-3330-SFF:~/.rviz$ rostopic list
/InertialData
/basler_node/basler_camera/parameter_descriptions
/basler_node/basler_camera/parameter_updates
/basler_node/camera_info
/basler_node/image_raw
/clock
/diagnostics
/hw_errors
/move_base_simple/goal
/nodder_angle
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/sr_lidar1_pcl
/sr_lidar1_scan
/tf
/velodyne_nodelet_manager/bond
/velodyne_packets
/velodyne_points
```

when i run the bag file Velodyne_points (pointcloud) only displayed in rviz ,,don display like this.....

we wants to display sr_lidar1_scan and nodder_angle information from 2D Lidar bag file.Can anyone suggest steps or procedure to generate a display using this information in rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67637/how-to-display-2d-lidar-data-in-rviz-with-sr_lidar1_scan-and-nodder_angle/) by [sivan chinnaiyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/5404/sivan-chinnaiyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What data type is that topic? If it's a LaserScan, just add a Laser Scan display in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0